# How to create a dataset from an xsd schema in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, dataset

I searched for this here and on msdn but didn't find a satisfactory answer either because things changed from 2005/2008 to 2010 or I don't know how to use VS IDE. 
So, here is what I am trying to I have an xsd file and I want to perform searching operations on that. For that I figured that I would need corresponding classes and dataset is the way to go. I created a dataset from file system(don't want to make it complex) and trying to link the schema and xsd that I have. 
I also read that there is a way to create a class(ORM) such that whenever I make changes to the schema the class is also updated.

Links to MSDN articles that I read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk6y3s8y.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720235.aspx

Comment: Part of your problem may be that you were looking at .NET 1.1 / Visual Studio 2003 links.

Comment: On top, why would you ever makie a dataset out of a Schema, and not a bunch of faster, smaller and more efficient and safe classes?

Comment: This is a shame. A question with over 10K views has just 1 Upvote

Answer (score 2):

Yes XSD.exe will generate (among other things) a C# class and/or a dataset for a given schema (use the /c switch for generating classes and /d for generating a dataset).

If you are using VS.net 2008 (and perhaps VS.net 2010; I dont have 2010), you can right click on your project and select "Add new item" - select the Dataset template and the IDE will automatically generate the class files for you.

Comment: Here how do I associate the xsd file that I have already with the newly created dataset (which is again a xsd... cofusing)

Comment: You do not. Generation is a one time process. NO further association is needed.